# How to build 1d array and find the number that are odd and divisible by 5?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a code that create a array of integers than the system check the entered number and find the odd and divisible number by 5 than it display the sum of this numbers.

but the problem is that my code did not show display anything

so how to fix my code?

**This is my code:**

```
package question2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOdd5 {


    static int[] array = new int[15];
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter numbers");
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
            array[i]=sc.nextInt();

        }
        sumOddDiv5();
    }

    public static int sumOddDiv5(){
        int sum;
        int odd = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){

            if(array[i] % 2 !=0 && array[i] % 5 ==0){
                odd++;
            }
        }
        sum = sum + odd;
    return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably homework about the modulo operator, so I guess you are supposed to check "odd" and "divisible by 5". But note that both conditions amount to checking that `number % 10 == 5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your problem statement says your code not printing `sum`,
1. You have not used `sum` variable to do sum.
2. You need to return your sum to print.

```
 public class SumOdd5 {
    static int[] array = new int[15];
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter numbers");
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
            array[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        int sum = sumOddDiv5();
        System.out.println("Sum of Number : "+sum);
    }

    public static int sumOddDiv5(){
        int sum=0;
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){

            if(array[i] % 2 !=0 && array[i] % 5 ==0){
                  sum +=array[i]; 
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: remove odd++ and replace it with sum +=array[i] to provide sum of all odd nos. divisible by 5.

Comment: i tried your code but it give a wrong result      ...............Enter numbers
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
12
13
14
151
16
16
total = 262
Number of  odd Numbers: 1

Comment: have you change array size to `15`?

Comment: what you mean by change array size to 15 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine (though it can be simplified),
but you have to display the output of your method in order to see it:

```
System.out.println(sumOddDiv5());
```

EDIT:

Actually, you are computing the number of odd inputs divisible by 5, not their sum, so instead of `odd++` you should add the current number to the total.

In addition, you can simplify your condition to :

```
if(array[i] % 10 == 5)
```

since you are looking for numbers ending in 5.

Comment: That would display the count of odd numbers that were divisible by 5. Not the sum (as in the requirements).

Comment: @Dave Yep, I missed that part

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements, this block looks wrong to me:

```
if(array[i] % 2 !=0 && array[i] % 5 ==0){
    odd++;
}
```

You're incrementing a counter, but you're not creating a sum of odd numbers. Nor are you printing it. Try this:

```
int total = 0;
if ( array[i] % 2 != 0 && array[i] % 5 != 0) { // it's an odd number
    total += array[i];
}
System.out.println("Total: " + total);
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise you have asked for an error check rather than suggestions but I'm just wondering if you've considered using Java 8 streams for this?

```
Arrays.stream(array)
    .filter(n -> n % 2 != 0)
    .filter(n -> n % 5 == 0)
    .sum();
```